# Reorder panel items in MATE 1.16

Tags: 16.10, panel, mate

Last time I tried Ubuntu MATE Live 16.04, there was a dedicated panel editor application which made reordering items on the panel easy.

Now, I have installed Ubuntu (default) 16.10 and decided to install MATE over Unity. I cannot find the application to configure the panels in this installation, which makes it impossible to move panel items which cannot be dragged.

Is this program installable or should I install Ubuntu Mate from scratch?

Answer (score 3):

For *some panel applets*, there is a "Move" item in their right click menus -- Workspace Switcher and Window List, for example. For ones that do, just select the "Move" item and drag the app around.

(This isn't a solution for all applets but it's a start.)