# Where has the panel editor gone

Tags: mate, panel, ubuntu-mate, gnome-panel, gnome-classic

This question is about ubuntu mate (gnome 2). When you wanted to change the layout of a panel you would right click and select the settings for that panel to edit the contents of that panel in the good old days of ubuntu 10.04.

But I can't find this option in 18.04 ubuntu mate.

How do I get a list view of the contents of a panel with the option to reorder, configure, add or delete items on that panel?

edit:
Heck even the whole panel management is missing?

Comment: What happens when you *right-click* the panel and select *Properties* or *Add to Panel*?

Comment: Add to panel just gives me a selection of widgets to add, and properties is a way stripped down version of what I expect.

Comment: Are you able to *right-click* on the panel items, select *Unlock* and then *Move* to move them were you want?

Comment: Yeah but I want real control instead of that

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that this editor is gone in MATE (I'm not 100% sure, since I don't use MATE currently). Moving items by dragging seems to be the only option now. Also see [this related question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879436/reorder-panel-items-in-mate-1-16).